# How to create e-commerce website with Firebase

Tags: firebase

Is it possible to create a website like Alibaba with Firebase?  if so, what languages ​​or technologies should I use.

I know HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a very broad question, however, the [official Firebase Quickstart Samples for Web](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js) is a really good place to start.

You can use several Firebase services such as:

- [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) which provides fast and secure hosting for your web app, static and dynamic content, and microservices.
- [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) which provides backend services, easy-to-use SDKs, and ready-made UI libraries to authenticate users to your app. It supports authentication using passwords, phone numbers, popular federated identity providers like Google, Facebook and Twitter, and more.
- [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) to store and serve user-generated content, such as photos or videos.
- [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) or [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) to store extra data. Be sure to check the documentation about [choosing the correct database for you](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore).

[Firebase guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides) are also a good place to find very well explained examples. Good luck!